# How to deploy rails application running locally(on my laptop) to live server (of my university) for local access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I am building an application for the students of my university. I am using ruby on rails for this and that application is running on my laptop at http://localhost:3000/ 
Now we have servers running in our university and I want to deploy my rails application on those servers so that students can access the application locally in the university. 
I am new to rails so please help me in doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question should be directed to your university's IT department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is unrelated to Rails or Ruby. It has to do with servers and deploying code in general.

1) Your university might have servers but they are privately owned by the university and you will have to ask the IT department if you can deploy your code on them.

2) If you get permission to deploy your app, you will have to have a way to scale and access your app or else it might crash once more traffic comes in or there is a bug. In order to scale, you will have to either physically access the server each time or use Secure Shell (SSH) which the university might not like because it would give you access to the server remotely which is a security risk.

3) How you deploy your app will depend on how the server is set up. Generally you will have to send your code from your local machine to the server through a Git repository. Then you have to make sure that Ruby, Rails and all the dependencies (gems) are installed. Then you have to choose an application server (Puma, Unicorn, Web brick,etc.) and a web server (Apache, NginX). 
Follow these instruction to get an idea of how to do all that:
https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/rails-deployment/

After these 3 steps you should be done more or less. It is obviously much easier to pay Amazon Web services (AWS) or Heroku and deploy your app there, especially when you expect low traffic.

PS: Your University's IT department might actually help you if they agree.